# postman post request for Azure FormRecognizer does not work

Tags: azure, post, postman, azure-form-recognizer

I am trying to follow the instructions [here](https://westus2.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api/operations/AnalyzeWithCustomModel) to analyze a form. I have already trained a model and it works when I use the python code. Now, I would like to be able to get the results also per `postman` but it doesn't work.

You can see my post request here:
[image]
[image]

As you see, I have added the `Content-Type` and the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`. However, I don't get any `json` as the answer, though I get `status: 202 Accepted`.

Can anybody tell me, what I have done wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have got a response with code `202 Accepted`, this means Azure has accepted your request and start to recognize your images.

In response header, there will be an URL named: `operation-location`
[image]

You can get the result that you requested for via this URL:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me to somehow. But now, I have another problem. When I use the other url that you introduced, I get `The file submitted couldn't be parsed. This can be due to one of the following reasons: the file format is not supported ( Supported formats include JPEG, PNG, BMP, PDF and TIFF), the file is corrupted or password protected.`, though the file can be analyzed using the python code.

Comment: It is weird, I have not met this kind of error before,could you please share whole of your request and image so that I can repro this issue on my side?

Answer (score 1):

Please also use the below reference REST APIs as the linked share in the original message is for Form Recognizer v1 release which has been deprecated. Please use the Form Recognizer v2 or v2.1 release.

[Form Recognizer v2.1 release REST API reference](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-1-preview-2/operations/AnalyzeBusinessCardAsync)

[Form Recognizer v2.0 release REST API reference](https://westus2.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2/operations/AnalyzeWithCustomForm)